# C++ Send image client to server (sockets), image corrupt

Tags: c++, sockets

after hours I write this :

Client side : Here I have image.png ( original image )

```
     FILE* fichier = fopen("image.png", "r");
        if(fichier != NULL)
        {
            response += "Analyse... ";

            fseek(fichier, 0, SEEK_END);
            long taille = ftell(fichier);
            fseek(fichier, 0, SEEK_SET);


            char chaine[taille];
            fread(chaine, 1, taille -1, fichier);

             string toSendTaille = to_string(taille);
            send(client_socket, toSendTaille.c_str(), toSendTaille.size()+1, 0);
            int debut = 0;

            while(debut < taille)
            {
                int erl = (taille - debut);
                int ofor = (erl > 10024 ) ? 10024  : erl;
                char aenvoyerchaine[ofor];
                for(int i=0; i < ofor; i++)
                {
                    aenvoyerchaine[i] = chaine[i + debut];
                }

                debut += ofor;
                string tlofor = to_string(ofor);

                send(client_socket, tlofor.c_str(), tlofor.size(), 0);
                send(client_socket, aenvoyerchaine, ofor, 0);
                Sleep(50);
            }
            delete [] chaine;
        }
        else
            response += " FAIL !";
```

Server side : I want to save a copy of the original image, in my file.

```
  long taille = atol(buffer);
        int action=0;


    bool isFirst = true;
    int sizeOf = 0;
    FILE* fout = fopen("C:/Users/pigeon/Documents/testPigeonVs/server/ServerProject/bin/Debug/reception.png", "w");
    while(action < taille)
    {
        if(isFirst){
            char firstSize[100]{ 0 };
            recv(client_socket, firstSize, sizeof(firstSize), 0);
            sizeOf = atoi(firstSize);
            isFirst = false;
        } else {
             char recep[sizeOf];
            int sizeRecep = sizeof(recep);
            recv(client_socket, recep, sizeRecep, 0);
            action = (action + sizeRecep);
            isFirst = !isFirst;
            sizeOf = 0;
            fwrite(recep,1,sizeRecep, fout);
            cout << "WRITE : " <<sizeRecep << endl;

        }
    }

    fclose(fout);
```

Result :
I have a reception.png file, with exactly the same size as the original picture.
But the image cannot be displayed. I have  "It seems to me that we do not support this file format".

A idea ?

Comment: `fread(chaine, 1, taille -1, fichier);` but fread only takes four arguments.

Comment: Yes I know,  : 1 - Chaine  || 2 -  1 || 3 -  taille -1 || 4 - fichier

Comment: If this is C++, why not use `ifstream`?

Comment: `char chaine[taille];` is non-standard syntax. Why not use a `std::vector<char> chaine(taille);`?

Comment: Both client and server are opening their files in TEXT mode, they need to open in BINARY mode instead.

Comment: You keep ignoring the return value of `recv`, so you keep throwing away data that you received in some cases or thinking you received more data than you received in others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many problems with this code, it just needs to be re-written from scratch.  Reading and sending the file data in chunks is fine, but you don't need to convert those chunks to strings (especially since you are doing it incorrectly), and you certainly don't need to send each chunk's size.  All you really need to send is the file's total size, and then you can send/receive the file data as-is until that size is reached.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
bool sendAll(SOCKET sckt, void *data, size_t size)
{
    char *p = static_cast<char*>(data);
    while (size > 0)
    {
        int numSent = send(sckt, p, size, 0);
        if (numSent < 0)
            return false;
        p += numSent;
        size -= numSent;
    }
    return true;
}

bool sendUInt32(SOCKET sckt, uint32_t value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    return sendAll(sckt, &value, sizeof(value));
}

...

std::ifstream fichier("image.png", std::ios::binary);

if (fichier.is_open())
{
    response += "Analyse... ";

    std::vector<char> data((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fichier)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    /* or:
    fichier.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streampos fileSize = fichier.tellg();
    fichier.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<char> fichier_data(fileSize);
    fichier.read(fichier_data.data(), fileSize);
    */

    fichier.close();
    
    uint32_t taille = fichier_data.size();

    bool ok = sendUInt32(client_socket, taille);
    if (ok && taille > 0)
        ok = sendAll(client_socket, fichier_data.data(), taille);

    if (!ok)
        response += " FAIL !";
}
else
    response += " FAIL !";
```

```cpp
bool recvAll(SOCKET sckt, void *data, size_t size)
{
    char *p = static_cast<char*>(data);
    while (size > 0)
    {
        int numRead = recv(sckt, p, size, 0);
        if (numRead <= 0)
            return false;
        p += numRead;
        size -= numRead;
    }
    return true;
}

bool recvUInt32(SOCKET sckt, uint32_t &value)
{
    bool ok = recvAll(sckt, &value, sizeof(value));
    if (ok) value = ntohl(value);
    return ok;
}

...

uint32_t taille;
if (!recvUInt32(client_socket, taille))
{
    std::cerr << "READ : error" << endl;
}
else
{
    std::ofstream fout("C:/Users/pigeon/Documents/testPigeonVs/server/ServerProject/bin/Debug/reception.png", std::ios::binary);
    if (!fout.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "FILE : error" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        char recep[1024];
        uint32_t action = 0;

        while (action < taille)
        {
            uint32_t sizeRecep = std::min(taille - action, sizeof(recep));
            if (!recvAll(client_socket, recep, sizeRecep))
            {
                std::cerr << "READ : error" << endl;
                break;
            }
            if (!fout.write(recep, sizeRecep))
            {
                std::cerr << "FILE : error" << endl;
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "WRITE : " << sizeRecep << endl;
            action += sizeRecep;
        }
    }
    fout.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sender:

```
send(client_socket, toSendTaille.c_str(), toSendTaille.size()+1, 0);
```

And in your receiver:

```
recv(client_socket, firstSize, sizeof(firstSize), 0);
```

If you review the description of both `send()` and `recv()` in your textbook, you will find it explained how neither of these functions will give you any guarantees that the exact number of bytes that's specified by their third parameter will be sent to received.

`send()` may end up sending fewer than the requested number of bytes.

`recv()` may end up receiving any number of bytes, up to the number of bytes specified by its size parameter.

The actual number of bytes that gets sent or received depends entirely on your operating system and networking condition.

Your code assumed that everytihng was sent and received, but ended up sending/and receiving random garbage data.

`send()`'s and `recv()`'s return value specifies how many bytes were actually sent and received, or if an error occured. You will need to modify your entire program and add the appropriate logic to handle the actual number of bytes sent or received, over the socket, and then trying again to send and receive the remaining data, until everything is sent and received.

You cannot ignore the return value of these system calls. You must check what's actually sent or received, and proceed accordingly. This applies to your every `send()` and `recv()` call.